# Angular service is undefined when fetching backend data in its constructor

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors, angular7

I have a `SessionService` which manages JWT token and stores user data. When my app is started I need to fetch user data from backend via http. It might be a bad idea, but since there is no `ngOnInit()` for services I do it in `SessionService` constructor:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionService {
    constructor(
        private errHandler: ErrorHandlingService,
        private backend:    UsersService
    ) {
        const initialToken = this.rawToken; // localStorage.getItem('jwt')
        if (!initialToken || this.isTokenExpired(initialToken)) {
            localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
            return;
        }
        this.fetchUser();
    }

    private fetchUser() {
        this.backend.getMe().subscribe(
            user => this.user = user,
            err  => this.errHandler.handle(err)
        );
   }
   /* ... */
}
```

I think this is pretty straightforward, `UsersSevice::getMe()` is just an abstraction for:

```
    getMe() {
        return this.http.get<Api.V1.Me.Get.Response>('/api/v1/me');
    }
```

The problem is that my `HttpInterceptor` that attaches JWT to the header of each http request, that it obtains via my `SessionService`gets this service as `undefined`, so the `TypeError` is raised when accessing its `rawRoken` getter (`can not read property rawToken of undefined`)

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private session: SessionService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const rawToken = this.session.rawToken;
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

I have found a workaround to wrap my `this.fetchUser()` call with `setTimeout(() => this.fetchUser(), 0)`, but why do I have to postpone this to another turn of event loop? That is my question. Please tell me, what rule am I violating?

Comment: Sounds like your sessions service hasn't be instantiated yet by the time it's called in your service. At what point of your applications lifecycle does that happen? It's definitely a timing issue.

Comment: @Mickers I've suddenly realized why this happens. Its because I do an http request in my SessionService constructor and my http interceptor is called synchronously for that request, but I haven't escaped my SessionService constructor function yet. Yeah, that was unexpected. My SessionService and JwtInterceptor just have implicit circular dependency through the HttpClient.

Comment: Glad that helped